# Composition of decreasing functions is increasing

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

I want to prove the following:

> If $f$ and $g$ are decreasing functions on $I$ and $f \circ g$ is defined on $I$, then $f \circ g$ is increasing on $I$.

**My attempt**:

Let $x_1,x_2$ be in $I$ such that $x_1\lt x_2$ and let $f$ and $g$ be decreasing. Then $f(x_1)\gt f(x_2)$ and $g(x_1)\gt g(x_2)$.

Then $(f \circ g)(x_1)= f(g(x_1))$ and $(f \circ g)(x_2)=f(g(x_2))$. Consequently, we have

$$f(g(x_1)) < f(g(x_2))$$

so $f \circ g$ is increasing on $I$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x_1,x_2$ be such that $x_1 \leq x_2$, then $y_1=g(x_1)\geq y_2=g(x_2)$ and so $f(y_1)\leq f(y_2)$, that is $f\circ g(x_1)\leq f\circ g(x_2)$.